# Join the text of the selected options of a select2 and set the value of an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have an input box and a select2 multiselect element.

Upon selection of a new option, I want the selected options' texts to be merged using a pipe character and fill in the input box.

One thing that's needed, is that my options may have a trailing -, which I need to trim before merging its text. Basically this worked well until I used .each() to take the text of every selected option... Can someone fix that for me? TIA.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#elems').select2();
  });

  $('#elems').on('change', function() {
    var myvalue = $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(this) {
      return $(this).text().replace(/^[-]+/, '') + '|';
    });







    $('#total').val(myvalue);

    //alert($(this).find('option:selected').text().replace(/^[-]+/, ''));
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="total">
</div>
<div>
  <select id="elems" name="elems[]" multiple>
    <option value="one">-One</option>
    <option value="two">--Two</option>
    <option value="three">---Three</option>
    <option value="four">----Four</option>
    <option value="five">-----Five</option>
    <option value="six">------Six</option>
    <option value="seven">-------Seven</option>
    <option value="eight">--------Eight</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is using `each` when you are attempting to convert or retrieve the `text()` from each selected element.

in this case [map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) is what you are looking for.  this essentially calls your function for each element (I know confusing) and combining the results into a **new** array.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#elems').select2();
  });

  $('#elems').on('change', function() {
  //notice map instead of each
    var myvalue = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function(i, opt) {
      return $(opt).text().replace(/^[-]+/, '');
    })
    .get()  //get the actual strings
    .join("|"); //join the strings with a pipe
    $('#total').val(myvalue);
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="total">
</div>
<div>
  <select id="elems" name="elems[]" multiple>
    <option value="one">-One</option>
    <option value="two">--Two</option>
    <option value="three">---Three</option>
    <option value="four">----Four</option>
    <option value="five">-----Five</option>
    <option value="six">------Six</option>
    <option value="seven">-------Seven</option>
    <option value="eight">--------Eight</option>
  </select>
</div>
```